# When creating stored procedure in Snowflake is there a way to return same output as a query, executed within it?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a stored procedure that sets the certain variable value and executes merge using this variable. Currently, it just returns a hardcoded message "Successfully executed.".
Is it possible to return the same result as the original merge query returns, like

> number of rows inserted
>
> number of rows updated

?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ALERTS_MERGE_PROCEDURE ()
RETURNS STRING NOT NULL
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
    $$
    var sql_command = '
    MERGE INTO tablename
..
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ...
);
    '
    snowflake.execute(
        {
        sqlText: sql_command
        });
    return "Successfully executed.";
    $$;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the columns of the first row of the returned object from the execution:

```sql
create or replace temp table tablename as
select 1::int  id, 'a'::string tx;

create or replace temp table tablesource as
select 1::int  id, 'b'::string tx 
union select 2, 'c';

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ALERTS_MERGE_PROCEDURE ()
RETURNS STRING NOT NULL
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
    var sql_command = `
    merge into tablename a
    using tablesource b
    on a.id = b.id 
    when matched then update set tx=b.tx
    when not matched then insert (id, tx) values (b.id, b.tx);
    `;
    var x = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_command});
    x.next();
    var result = '';
    for (i=1; i<=x.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        result += x.getColumnName(i) + ': ' + x.getColumnValue(i) + '\n'; 
    }
    return result;
$$;
    
call alerts_merge_procedure();
```

Returns:

```
number of rows inserted: 1
number of rows updated: 1
```

Comment: why would you not use e.g. getNumRowsInserted() - or am I missing something?

Comment: Because I tried and I couldn't make it work 

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look at the methods of the statement object. This is all documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#object-statement